# Posting image to friends wall android 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

process for uploading image to friends wall,
frist uploading image to user wall, and den in response getting image id and link,

unable to post image on friends wall,please suggest me if any fb configuration and fb permissions needed?

```
if (hasPublishPermission()) {

        RequestBatch requestBatch = new RequestBatch();

        for (GraphUser friend : selectedFriends) {

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            Constants.showLog(TAG, String.valueOf(friend.getFirstName()));
            parameters.putString("message", "Greetings!!");
            parameters.putString("link", imagelink);
            parameters.putString("picture", imagelink);
            parameters.putString("target_id", friend.getId());

            requestBatch.add(new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), friend.getId() + "/feed", parameters,
                    HttpMethod.POST));

            Constants.showToast(this, "Posted picture on your friends wall");

        }

        requestBatch.addCallback(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onBatchCompleted(RequestBatch batch) {
                Constants.showLog(TAG, "Posted to :" + batch.size());
            }
        });

        Request.executeBatchAsync(requestBatch);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Feb 6th breaking changes here https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

Namely: "Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API".

You are no longer able to directly post to a friend's wall via Graph requests. You need to use the feed dialog.